# How do I remove a glued pvc wastepipe

Tags: plumbing, pipe, pvc

I have removed an old sink from a bedroom and was looking to remove the old waste pipe. It appears to be glued to another main waste pipe, see below

[image]
so my idea was to remove the horizontal pipe and cap it off somehow, but I’m not sure how to remove it

Comment: That big joint looks like a clean out, with the cap having a hole cut into it.  If the cap was not glued, then it should a simple job to unscrew the cap and replace with a new one.  Hope it was not glued, if so cut the small pipe and get a joint with a cap for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a strange reducer cap to me. There's a name stamped on it so it doesn't appear to be a hack job. Just cut the horizontal pipe two inches from the reducer plate. You can use a regular hack saw. Then get a cap from your home store and cement it to the remaining piece of pipe.

If the reducer cap can be removed, get a piece of pipe to fit into the tee and then cap that.

Comment: Looks like an ordinary Sanitary Tee that the reducer is glued into, so I would not anticipate removal being practical (there are ways, but they are chancy and/or expensive for something that may not be needed,) while a simple cut and cap is reliable and straightforward and inexpensive.

Comment: @Ecnerwal  Agreed. I have never seen an off center reducer like that.